# How to use Json in c# project metro apps

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

We developed project in C# and we want to use js library or Json calls in project. is it possible? How can we use js library in C# project in Windows 8 metro apps?? is there any sample so please share link thanks.

Comment: We developed project in C# and we want to use js library or Json calls in project. is it possible?

Comment: if i say simply "yes" to this question... Please just read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq first and try to explain more about your real problem. Is your problem just implementing js libraries or how to use json or windows 8 metro apps? This question seems more like a superuser question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot use `C#` and `JavaScript` for Win8 development together. Notice that the rendering engines for the two technologies are even different. If you want to utilize some `JSON` returning service in your `XAML WinRT` app you can still do that. All you need to do is deserialize the `JSON` after fetching it.